# Pandas - Build sequnce in the group while resetting on defined condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am kind of stuck with my learning knowledge. I thought this is the time I seek help from experts.

Here I have to build a 'result column' based on my patient & schedule columns.
-- Condition 1: Sequence need to be reset if a patient change in the patient column
-- Condition 2. The sequence needs to reset within the patient if schedule = 000

This is my sample dataset:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'patient': ['one', 'one', 'one', 'one','two', 'two','two','two','two'],    
                    'schedule': ['111', '111', '000', '111', '111', '000','111','111','111'],        
                    'date': ['11/20/2022', '11/22/2022', '11/23/2022', '11/8/2022', '11/9/2022', '11/14/2022','11/20/2022', '11/22/2022', '11/23/2022']})
```

This is my result or intended data frame (new column I like to see is 'result':

```
result = pd.DataFrame({'patient': ['one', 'one', 'one', 'one','two', 'two','two','two','two'],    
                    'schedule': ['111', '111', '000', '111', '111', '000','111','111','111'],        
                    'date': ['11/20/2022', '11/22/2022', '11/23/2022', '11/8/2022', '11/9/2022', '11/14/2022','11/20/2022', '11/22/2022', '11/23/2022'],
                    'result': ['1st_Time', '2nd_Time', 'Reset', '1st_Time', '1st_Time', 'Reset','1st_Time','2nd_Time','3rd_Time']})
```

Thank you so much for all your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create subgroups for each patient whenever you encounter '000':

```
m = df2['schedule'] == '000'
df2['result'] = (df2[~m].groupby(['patient', m.cumsum()])
                        .cumcount().add(1)
                        .reindex(df2.index, fill_value=0))
print(df2)

# Output
  patient schedule        date  result
0     one      111  11/20/2022       1
1     one      111  11/22/2022       2
2     one      000  11/23/2022       0
3     one      111   11/8/2022       1
4     two      111   11/9/2022       1
5     two      000  11/14/2022       0
6     two      111  11/20/2022       1
7     two      111  11/22/2022       2
8     two      111  11/23/2022       3
```

You can also build a dict mapping to convert integer to string:

```
int2str = {0: 'Reset', 1: '1st_Time', 2: '2nd_Time', 3: '3rd_Time'}
df2['result'] = df2['result'].map(int2str)
print(df2)

# Output
  patient schedule        date    result
0     one      111  11/20/2022  1st_Time
1     one      111  11/22/2022  2nd_Time
2     one      000  11/23/2022     Reset
3     one      111   11/8/2022  1st_Time
4     two      111   11/9/2022  1st_Time
5     two      000  11/14/2022     Reset
6     two      111  11/20/2022  1st_Time
7     two      111  11/22/2022  2nd_Time
8     two      111  11/23/2022  3rd_Time
```